# GetMapping with JSON array parameter

Tags: java, feign, get-mapping

I am using a FeignClient and a GetMapping to interact with an external system.
My GetMapping is defined as:

```
   @GetMapping(value = "/path/to/endpoint?fields=[\"nm\",\"label\"]")
   public String hitEndpoint() {}
```

Debug shows that the endpoint is being called with:

```
https://url/path/to/endpoint?fields=[%22nm%22&fields=%22label%22]
```

Which is failing because the endpoint expects valid json for the fields parameter:

```
https://url/path/to/endpoint?fields=[%22nm%22,%22label%22]
```

How do I convince GetMapping to make the request correctly?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Although I think its better to pass `JSON` as body of a `POST` method to your controller. But if you insist on doing this I can propose to you 2 solutions:

### First Solution

Encode your `JSON` array into [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) so you can send it via `URL`.

For example, your array will be like this:

`["nm","label"]` -> `%5B%22nm%22%2C%22label%22%5D`

I used [this](https://www.urlencoder.org/) online tool to encode it.

### Second Solution

1. Encode your array into `Base64` and `GET` it via URL to your controller.
2. Decode the given `Base64` string in the controller and parse it as a `JSON` array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to define your Array parameter in the URL, using spring you can define your API as below and with the power of `@RequestParam` annotation you can define that you expect to receive an array as a parameter in the URL

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path-to-endpoint", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<YourResponseDTO> yourMethodName(
@RequestParam("ids") List<Long> arrayParam) {
        // Return successful response
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.yourServiceMethod(requestDTO), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Then you can call your `GET` endpoint using below URL:

```
/path-to-endpoint?ids=1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately, I do not control the actual endpoint and am trying to use a feignclient to talk to it.